# Can't finish compiling a process with while loop

Tags: vhdl

I have the following process, which is supposed to right-shift its input (input_1) until it reaches 0 and then end the loop:

```
DFF_PROCESS: process (input_0, input_1, input_2, CLK)
  variable eX : integer;
  ...
begin
  eX := input_1;
  ...
  while (eX > 0) loop
    if ( CLK'event and CLK = '1' ) then
      ...
      eX := to_integer(shift_right(to_unsigned(eX,32), 1));
    end if;
  end loop;
  result <= rE;
end process;
```

But when I try to compile it, it does not generate any errors, but gets stuck at ~10% of the Analysis&Synthesis part. The compiler seems to be working (checked via ProcessExplorer), however even after more than an hour, there was no progress.
Can anyone help?

I need this component to be synthesisable, so if my approach has a logical flaw, please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synthesising a while loop is usually a bad idea, and a little thought will show why...

While loops are not guaranteed to terminate; and the number of iterations cannot *generally* be known at compile (synthesis) time - therefore you are trying to generate a hardware structure whose size is unknown until runtime!

That won't work...

Typically you need to transform the While loop into a closely related For loop with locally static bounds (roughly : can be determined from this source file) - which is synthesisable.

In your case you are converting the variable to a 32-bit unsigned and shifting it right 1 bit at a time : a suitable For loop would loop over the bits in a 32-bit unsigned.

That doesn't cope with differing input values : however a conditional ( `if ex = 0 then` ) inside the for loop will do that (and obviously is synthesisable)

Something like...

```
DFF_PROCESS: process (CLK, input_1)
variable eX : unsigned(31 downto 0);
    ...
begin
    eX := to_unsigned(input_1);
    ...
    for i in ex'range loop  -- better way of saying 31 downto 0)
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if ex > 0 then
               ...   
               eX := shift_right(eX, 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end loop;
end process;
```

This has other problems : it's not a proper clocked process, and ex is continually overwritten by the input value so it won't do what you expect.

There are two ways forward : one fast (one result per clock cycle) but generating lots of hardware, the other small (but it'll take 32 clock cycles worst case).

The first unrolls the loop, generating 32 copies of the loop body, to generate a result in a single clock cycle :

```
DFF_PROCESS: process (CLK)
variable eX : unsigned(31 downto 0);
    ...
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        eX := to_unsigned(input_1, ex'length);
        ...
        for i in ex'range loop  
            if ex > 0 then  -- done
               ...
               eX := shift_right(eX, 1);
            end if;
        end loop;
        result <= ...
    end if;
end process;
```

The other is a state machine which can either accept a new input value, or process a single bit, but not both, in each clock cycle.

```
DFF_PROCESS: process (CLK)
   variable eX : unsigned(31 downto 0);
   type State_type is (Read, Process_Data);
   variable State : State_Type;

begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      if State = Read then
         eX    := to_unsigned(input_1, ex'length);
         State := Process_Data;
      else
         if ex = 0 then
            result <= ...
            State := Read;
         else
            ...
            eX := shift_right(eX, 1);
         end if;
      end if;
   end if;
end process;
```

(You can add states to make it wait before Reading a new value if you wish...)

Comment: thanks for the reply, gave me really some insight. however, even with your proposed changes, the issue persists: still can't finish compilation, gets A&S up to 80% thou

Comment: If that applies to the third version, I can only conclude there are problems with other (not shown) parts of your code. Start small (test the above) and work up till synthesis breaks.