# Calculating the GCD of two 8-bit numbers in VHDL and implementing on FPGA

Tags: vhdl

To calculate the GCD of two 8-bit numbers, I use this code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;

entity gcd_8bit is
Port (a: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
      b: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
      gcd: out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0));
end gcd_8bit;
architecture Behavioral of gcd_8bit is
begin
process(a,b)
variable av,bv: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
begin
av := a;
bv := b;
while (av/=bv) loop
    if (av<bv) then
        bv := bv-av;
    else
        av := av-bv;
    end if;
end loop;
gcd<=av;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

But it gives me an error:

```
loop condition does not converge after 2000 iterations
```

I literally do not understand where the mistake is, can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't finish compiling a process with while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204456/cant-finish-compiling-a-process-with-while-loop)

Comment: Too bad neither the linked question nor user_1818839's answer provide valid VHDL. A wavy handed question and answer with all the extra work developing and debugging a snippet into a [mcve]. The final snippet of the answer attempts to use a keyword as an identifier and is missing the second parameter in a to_unsigned call, as well as an entity and architecture providing context/declarations. Note user_1818839's response to the OP's comment after attempting to validate the answer.

Comment: Loops are unrolled in synthesis, the number of iterations must be deterministic. Historically no one attempted while loop synthesis (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, withdrawn due to lack of maintenance and participation by vendors). The particular Vivado error message covers a multitude of sins, determining here there are no set bounds to  the number of iterations. There are sets of a and b values that wouldn't finish simulating either (where there's likely a higher iteration limit today as well).

Comment: Add the testbench to the question. And in simulation, did you consider the behaviour of the loop condition in the presence of metavalues?

Comment: @user16145658 thanks for comments; specific ones fixed even though I doubt they would slow anyone down; others depend on missing info in question.

Comment: @kiosk Did you realize that if your `b` input is zero your while loop is infinite?

Comment: Questions aren't considered duplicates without up voted answers. See [How to implement the Greatest Common Divisor in Xilinx ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313899/how-to-implement-the-greatest-common-divisor-in-xilinx-vhdl).  While the question code is invalid for lots of reasons most not shared here, the second and third comments provide links to synthesis eligible solutions along the lines of Renaud Pacelet's answer as well as sequential (clocked) designs representing more mimal hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is infinite if `a=0` xor `b=0`. Logic synthesizers unroll loops. So, if you really want to synthesize such a combinatorial GCD operator you will need to handle the `a=0` and `b=0` cases, plus fix a maximum number of iterations (255 should be enough). But the result will probably be huge. A much better option would be to design a sequential machine with clock, reset, registers... to compute the GCD in a succession of clock cycles.

Anyway, just for fun, here is a combinatorial GCD operator that should synthesize... if your target FPGA is large enough:

```vhdl
    process(a, b)
        variable av, bv: std_ulogic_vector(7 downto 0);
    begin
        av := a;
        bv := b;
        if av = 0 then
            gcd <= bv;
        else
            gcd <= av;
        end if;
        for i in 1 to 255 loop
            if av = bv then
                gcd <= av;
            elsif av < bv then
                bv := bv - av;
            elsif bv < av then
                av := av - bv;
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;
```